# Python decimal precision and rounding

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I want to limit the precision of my float and use it as an exact value for next operations, but I'm doing something wrong with decimal module.

```
from decimal import *

factor = 350/float(255)

# Settings
getcontext().prec = 1
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_UP

print Decimal(factor)
```

Python output:
1.372549019607843145962533526471816003322601318359375

Expected and wanted result: 1.4

Comment: Simply creating a `Decimal` object doesn't round to the current context. For that, there's a trick: you can apply unary plus, as in `+Decimal(factor)`. Having said that, this still won't do what you want: `prec` refers to the total number of significant digits, not to the number of places after the point. So in this case, you'd want `prec=2`.

Comment: You may also want to look into the `Decimal.quantize` method.

Comment: Do you specifically want to round up, or just round to the nearest one-place-after-the-decimal-point float?

Comment: @JulienBernu `numpy.round` does not give you an exact representation. It is still binary floating point. The `decimal` library is needed.

Comment: `>>> getcontext().prec = 2; +Decimal(factor)` => `Decimal('1.4')`

Answer (score 0):

From Python Documentation: (https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

The significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding only come into play **during arithmetic operations**.

```
getcontext().prec = 6
Decimal('3.0')
Decimal('3.0')
Decimal('3.1415926535')
Decimal('3.1415926535')
Decimal('3.1415926535') + Decimal('2.7182818285')
Decimal('5.85987')
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_UP
Decimal('3.1415926535') + Decimal('2.7182818285')
Decimal('5.85988')
```

so you need to use decimal in operation, not when printing result.